# File Uploading with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

at the moment I'm using this: https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu for uploading files.

at the moment i'm running with rails 3.2.12 but soon I want to upgrade to 4.2

can I use this plugin with 4.2 or do I need to use another one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

attachment_fu is a very old plugin and from the github page it appears as if the development has stopped, so I doubt it will support Rails 4+

These are some good alternatives:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads

Carrierwave and paperclip are the most faous ones and pretty easy to setup.

Comment: thanks, Am I right that attachment_fu is only for validating?

Comment: it is more than just for validating. It is a full file upload solution which supports various providers like S3, Racksapce, etc. Details here: https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu. It is just that active development has stopped on this plugin and it will not store Rails 4. You can always create a fork and start maintaining it. I am sure the community will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is a smart choice for file uploading. You can use it in rails 3 & 4.